# Displaying an icon which redirects to a link, instead of data value in bootstrap-vue table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have the following data which is returned from an API

```js
let data = [
   {
    'doodle': 123,
    'moodle': 456,
    'link': 'wfw6f3gefvdf6w'
   },
    {
    'doodle': 123,
    'moodle': 496,
    'link': 'wsvsdvsd6fw7f6w'
  },
    {
    'doodle': 123,
    'moodle': 459,
    'link': 'wfw6fvsvf6w'
  },
    {
    'doodle': 123,
    'moodle': 406,
    'link': 'wfw6fvvfvf6w'
  }
]
```

displayed in the following table,

```html
<div>
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" aria-controls="journeyTable"></b-pagination>
    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <card :title="title" :subTitle="subTitle">
                <div slot="raw-content" class="table-responsive">
                    <b-table id="my-table" :items="data" :per-page="perPage" 
                    :current-page="currentPage" striped hover small></b-table>
                </div>
            </card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking at changing the "link" part of the data to an icon that redirects to the specified URL. How can this be achieved in bootstrap? I'm been using vuetify for some time now and messing around with templates and fields has my head in a spin.

Comment: What do you mean by _"redirects"_? How can an icon _redirect_?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained in a little more detail.

The data is a token, which should be appended on the end of a URL, this will be displayed as an icon, that when clicked with redirect. So a fancy looking href

Comment: Where should the link appear? in the table? You an create a custom formatted column using scoped slots: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering

Answer (score 2):

Use [named scoped slots](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering) as mentioned in the docs:

```html
<b-table
 id="my-table"
 :items="data"
 :per-page="perPage"
 :current-page="currentPage"
 striped
 hover
 small
>
  <!-- "link" is the name of the field in your data/fields -->
  <template slot="link" slot-scope="{ value }">
    <!-- this is just making a regular link -->
    <a href="`/some/util/${value}`">{{ value }}</a>
    <!-- or you could make an actionable badge -->
    <b-badge href="`/some/util/${value}`">{{ value }}</b-badge>
    <!-- or you could make an button with an icon/symbol -->
    <b-button href="`/some/util/${value}`">⇨</b-button>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

If using vue-router, and the link is local to your app, then use the `to` prop instead of the `href` prop on `b-button`, `b-badge`, or `b-link`, etc.

Comment: is this correct ^ ? I tried by using slots and didn't work. the below example worked for  me

                            <template #cell(link)="data">
                                <!-- this is just making a regular link -->
                                {{ data.link }}
                            </template>